# SwiftUI Change View with Edit Mode

Tags: swift, swiftui, iso, editmode

I try to change the view state according to edit mode, when is editing hide the view and when it's not editing show the view, when I use on change and print the edit mode value its work but its doesn't work when working with views.

```
struct TaskStateMark_Row: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var task: Task
    @Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode
    
    var body: some View {
        Group {
        // Show and hide the view according to edit mode state
            if let editMode = editMode?.wrappedValue {
                if editMode == .inactive {
                    taskState
                        .onTapGesture(perform: onTapAction)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    
    private var taskState: some View {
        Group {
            if task.isCompleted {
                completedState
            } else {
                incompletedState
            }
        }
        .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
    }
    
    private var incompletedState: some View {
        ZStack{
            fillCircle
            circle
        }
    }
    
    private var circle: some View {
        Image(systemName: "circle")
            .font(.system(size: 24))
            .foregroundColor(task.wrappedPriority.color)
    }
    
    private var fillCircle: some View {
        Image(systemName: "circle.fill")
            .font(.system(size: 24))
            .foregroundColor(task.wrappedPriority.color.opacity(0.15))
    }
    
    private var completedState: some View {
        Image(systemName: "checkmark.circle.fill")
            .symbolRenderingMode(.palette)
            .foregroundStyle(.white, task.wrappedPriority.color)
            .font(.system(size: 24))
    }    
    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer in the developer documentation in the follow link

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/editmode

The code

```
@Environment(\.editMode) private var editMode
@State private var name = "Maria Ruiz"

var body: some View {
    Form {
        if editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing == true {
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
        } else {
            Text(name)
        }
    }
    .animation(nil, value: editMode?.wrappedValue)
    .toolbar { // Assumes embedding this view in a NavigationView.
        EditButton()
    }
}
```